# how can we set the alarm of software update in android?

Tags: android

I don't want to receive any alarm of software update in android when I'm working?
So, is there any method that can set the time zone when I don't want receive that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to settings > About phone > Software Update > Uncheck Auto update.

Comment: I want to enable it at night. is is possible?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible but when my device is prompting me to update may software, I can postpone it to I think several hours, even days. However, I think that is the default feature of our devices when it comes to software update.